# Scan a String Set(SS) that contains a substring

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

Suppose I have the following schema:

```
id: S
my_list: SS
```

With the following example record:

```
{
    "id": "auniquestring",
    "list": [
        "item1",
        "item11",
        "item111",
        "item2",
        "item22",
        "item3"
    ]
```

I am scanning the table with the following params:

```
params = {
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":v1": {
            S: item_substring
        }
    },
    FilterExpression: "contains(list, contains(list_item, :v1))",
    TableName: "MyItemsTable"
};
```

The basic idea is to return the record that contains a string in a list of strings, containing the queried substring.

> Answer in JavaScript would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `FilterExpression` is not correct.  Why are you nesting `contains`?

Have you tried `FilterExpression: "contains(list,:v1)"`?

Comment: Yeah I have, it matches the string completely in the array. But I want to match it using the substring if it is present.